# how to access a remote IP camera using UID

Tags: networking, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, ip-camera

My colleague installed an IP camera and I want to access it to get frames from the stream. However, the IP provided is local, so I don't know how to access it. The access data I got looks like this:

```
Local IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
UID: XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX
User: XXXXXXXXXX
Password: XXXXXXXXXX
```

I have tried the usual options such as

```
rtsp://[IP Camera’s IP Address]
```

and

```
rtsp://admin:password0@LOCALIP/cam/channel1
```

but I don't get anything.

I guess the solution has to involve the UID, since the IP is local (something I don't really understand).

In particular, I need to use ffmpeg (or VLC) to get images (eg. every 10 minutes). So it has to be using the command line.

Any ideas?

Edit1 - additional information:

- The camera is installed in a workshop ca. 5 miles away (from my house) and connects to the internet via the mobile network.
- As far as I know, there is no router involved to edit port forwarding, etc.
- The camera is a cheap Chinese one, don't even remember the brand name (I didn't buy it, I just receive the login information stated above); but somewhere I remember having read that it should be ONVIF compatible (whatever it means)
- I can access the camera using an Android application, from which I can move the PTZ and change some settings (I need to enter username, password and UID to connect to the camera). That is not what I want tough, I just want to access the camera and get a picture every X minutes using ffmpeg or Python.

In general, the instructions I could find on the internet require only IP, user, password, and port number **to form a URL** that then is used with HTTP or RTSP, but I have not been able to get anything using that approach. But I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: What camera model? Are you on the same network the camera is connected? "local" in this context likely means the local network, and UID is just a unique identifier, and is not an address that means anything outside the camera itself.

Comment: I am not on the same network. I edited the question to add this and more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Accessing the Camera Remotely

Knowing the public-facing IP address of your colleague's network will get you to their modem/firewall.  Then, the firewall must accept the RTSP traffic and also route (forward) it to the camera.

You will need to complete the following steps:

1. **Setup Port Forwarding**    <sup><sub>**!**    see **Custom Ports** below</sub></sup>
   The router (co-located with the camera) will need to have the RTSP port forwarded to the camera's IP.  The default RTSP port is `554` and the port forwarding would be `554 → LocalIP:554`
2. **Get the Public IP**              <sup><sub>**!**    see  **Dynamic DNS** below</sub></sup>
   Instead of the local IP address, you will need to use the public IP address at the camera's location.  You can get the info from the router on the camera's network, by  Googling terms like ["my ip address"](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20ip%20address) or using a website like [whatismyipaddress.com](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)

#### Example URLs

<sub>**Local**</sub>
       `rtsp://192.168.1.45`
      
`rtsp://192.168.1.45:554`
       <sub>**Remote**</sub>
       `rtsp://23.227.38.65`
       `rtsp://23.227.38.65:554`
       `rtsp://23.227.38.65:4196`    *custom port*
       <sub>**Hostname (e.g. Dynamic DNS)**</sub>
       `rtsp://colleague.dynu.com`
       `rtsp://colleague.dynu.com:554`
       `rtsp://colleague.dynu.com:4196`    *custom port*

#### Custom Ports

Router port forwarding will map one-to-one relationships between public ports and `localIP:port` combinations.  If the public RTSP port `554` is already in use, or unavailable for any reason such as an ISP block, you need to use a custom port such as `4196` instead of `554`.  The forwarding would then be adapted with your custom port like this: `4196 → LocalIP:554`

When using a custom port, note the following:

1. You are safer choosing ports in the range `1024-49151` (IANA User Ports) and can always use the [IANA port search](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) to double-check that you aren't choosing a port that might conflict with existing traffic.
2. Including default protocol port numbers in addresses is optional however custom port numbers **must always** be included

| Port | Type | URLs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `554` | Default | ✔ `rtsp://<ipAddress>:554` ✔ `rtsp://<ipAddress>` |
| `4196` | Custom | ✔ `rtsp://<ipAddress>:4196` ❌ `rtsp://<ipAddress>` |

#### Dynamic DNS

If the Public IP address is dynamically allocated by the ISP, which is common, it could be subject to unannounced change.  This change can be extremely rare or frequent, depending on the ISP. A Dynamic DNS service such as [Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/FAQ/Dynamic-DNS-Service) can provide a permanent hostname that is updated behind the scenes to always point to the current Public IP.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed and comprehensive answer. I am not an expert in networks, but I have been told that something like this would expose the local network of the camera to security risks. I am unsure if there is anything I can do against that, but it would be a separate question.

Comment: @terauser Best way to mitigate the risk, if you want to allow external access, is to (1) ensure username/password are strong and unique, (2) access the network via a VPN. (3) Isolate high-risk IOT devices such as your cameras in a separate subnet from the main LAN.